# Mule ESB app deployment anchor file permission

Tags: deployment, mule, file-permissions, esb

I need some help pertaining to app anchor file permissions.

We are running Mule EE ESB 3.7.3 on RH 6.5 using an account called mulesvc.

We deploy apps using a different account, muledeploy.

When we go to deploy an app, mule sees the new deployment and creates an anchor file that has the permission of rw-r--r-- with the owner mulesvc.

The problem I now, is that the deployer account, muledeploy, does not have permissions to delete the anchor file to undeploy the app. The folder's permissions are set rwxrwsr-x.

Is there a way to configure mule to create anchor files with different permissions or at least inherent the folder permissions?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

So far, I have not had this kind of problem. You can try adding both users to the same group and assign that group to the folder Mule.

Something like that:

```
#groupadd muleadmin
#usermod -a -G muleadmin mulesvc
#usermod -a -G muleadmin muledeploy
#chown -R mulesvc:muleadmin /path/to/mule/folder/
```

Maybe the solution is more S.O side that Mule. Try it and comment us

Comment: Hi Alexis, thank you for the post. That takes care of the exploded files. But the anchor file's group permission is not set. Therefore it cannot be deleted by the deployer account.